# Where can I find and download ath10k-dkms_1.1_all.deb?

Tags: wireless

I just upgraded kernal and now my wireless is not working. I see everywhere thousands of suggestions to download ath10k-dkms_1.1_all.deb and install that package. I absolutely can not find it anywhere though. Where can I download it?

https://duckduckgo.com/?t=lm&q=ath10k-dkms_1.1_all.deb

https://media.8ch.net/vis/src/1448997354984.png

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device from the terminal: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` and also: `uname -r`. Welcome to askubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded the 1.0 version of mentioned file for you onto zippyshare, but
chances are high that it won't work (because of not being compatible with your kernel version).

You can download and try it from here:
http://www57.zippyshare.com/v/ZKRSkjlY/file.html

I had same problems like you and tdeb package didn't help (it didn't compile). I finally solved it -with the help of ppl from https://bugs.launchpad.net/hwe-next/+bug/1383184- by copying the firmware files from https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware to /lib/firmware
( `cp -r QCA6174/ /lib/firmware/QCA6174`)

Comment: lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 20)
 Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:0804]
 Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci